# How to make fully nested grids using sf in R?

Tags: r, sf, vector-grid

I am using `st_make_grid()` from the `sf` package to create grids of various resolutions, but I want the smaller one to be perfectly nested within the larger.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(spdep)

grid_sizes_km <- c(25, 50)
grid_sizes_deg <- grid_sizes_km*1000/111111


india_sf <- world %>% 
  filter(name_long == "India")

# g1
res <- 1 
cs <- grid_sizes_deg[res]
n <- (c(diff(st_bbox(india_sf)[c(1, 3)]), diff(st_bbox(india_sf)[c(2, 4)]))/cs) %>% ceiling()

g1_sf <- india_sf %>% 
  st_make_grid(cellsize = cs, n = n) %>% 
  st_as_sf() %>% 
  rename(geometry = x) %>% 
  # cell IDs
  rownames_to_column("GRID.G1")

# g2
res <- 2
cs <- grid_sizes_deg[res]
n <- (c(diff(st_bbox(india_sf)[c(1, 3)]), diff(st_bbox(india_sf)[c(2, 4)]))/cs) %>% ceiling()

g2_sf <- india_sf %>% 
  st_make_grid(cellsize = cs, n = n) %>% 
  st_as_sf() %>% 
  rename(geometry = x) %>% 
  # cell IDs
  rownames_to_column("GRID.G2")
```

Here, `g1_sf` should ideally have 4x more cells than `g2_sf`, but what I get is 3.96x.

```
> summary(g1_sf)
   GRID.G1                   geometry    
 Length:15990       POLYGON      :15990  
 Class :character   epsg:4326    :    0  
 Mode  :character   +proj=long...:    0  

> summary(g2_sf)
   GRID.G2                   geometry   
 Length:4030        POLYGON      :4030  
 Class :character   epsg:4326    :   0  
 Mode  :character   +proj=long...:   0
```

Comment: I don't see imperfect nesting of grid cells. If I use the bounds of India from the `rworldmap` package: `Bounding box:  xmin: 68.16507 ymin: 6.748684 xmax: 97.34355 ymax: 35.49592` I get one grid with 16640 cells and another with 4160 - exactly one-quarter. Can you tell us where you get your `world` from so we can reproduce your code, and it would help if you showed at least a summary of your output grids so we can check this.

Comment: I've chopped your question down to the first problem which is "why does halving the cell size not give 4x as many cells?"

Comment: Note that grids in spherical geometry can *never* really be perfectly nested since the intermediate corner points of the smaller cells won't lie on the great circles formed between the corners of the larger cells. But that shouldn't matter until you've managed to form a smaller grid with 4x the cells of the larger grid, which is the Q we have to solve first.

Comment: Sorry, I thought `world` was part of `sf` but I realised it is from `spdep`. I've updated the post with the package and sf object summaries

Comment: About chopping the post, my second question was related to this first one, and I think that's a potential solution for this, as long as the data structure issues can be sorted

Comment: If you check your intermediate steps, `n` is 130x123 for the first grid, and 65x62 for the second. Because you've got an odd number of cells in the small grid, you can't precisely divide by two (without one remainder small grid row...). If you make `n` for your big cell grid first, then use `n*2` for the small cell grid, it should work.

Comment: Yes, that does work, ostensibly. But spatially, not at all. `st_join(g2_sf, g1_sf) %>% 
  st_drop_geometry() %>% 
  group_by(GRID.G2) %>% 
  summarise(N = n_distinct(GRID.G1)) %>% 
  distinct(N)` shows that each of the bigger cells overlaps at least 9 smaller ones!

Comment: This might be the spherical geometry problem. But I seem to have got to the root of the problem of not getting 4x the number of cells. If you want to post a new Q showing that what should be a subdivision of a grid into smaller cells results in these 9-cell overlaps, you should maybe do that with a full reproducible example.

Comment: @Spacedman This was indeed my original issue, which I perhaps crudely oversimplified referring to the 4x cells--I found out that I wasn't getting exactly 4x whilst I was trying to debug the main issue.

Can it still be the spherical geometry problem if I've used `sf_use_s2(FALSE)`?

Comment: Try it with smaller numbers of cells so you can actually plot the thing and inspect what's going on. Also note that `st_make_grid(x, ns=..., cellsize=...)` ignores the bounding box of `x` because `ns` and `cellsize` define a grid themselves. Are you sure you've constructed nested cells?